LUKS-LVM-LUKS - double encryption
I have FDE (LUKS-LVM), but my home directories aren't encrypted for each users.
I have now:
sda
├─sda1 /boot
└─sda2
  └─crypto0 (luks)
    └─vg0-root (/)
    └─vg0-swap ([SWAP])
    └─vg0-home (/home, /home/julia, /home/anybody...)

I'll want to do:
sda
├─sda1 /boot
└─sda2
  └─crypto0 (luks)
    └─vg0-root (/)
    └─vg0-swap ([SWAP])
    └─vg0-home (/home)
    └─vg0-julia
      └─crypto1 (luks)
        └─vg1-root (/home/julia)
    └─vg0-bob
      └─crypto2 (luks)
        └─vg2-root (/home/bob)


At first I have thought about:
sda
├─sda1 /boot
└─sda2
  └─crypto0 (luks)
    └─vg0-root (/)
    └─vg0-swap ([SWAP])
    └─vg0-home (/home)
└─sda3
  └─crypto1 (luks)
    └─vg1-root (/home/julia)
└─sda4
  └─crypto2 (luks)
    └─vg2-root (/home/bob)

But I think the latter case will be less secure because the data thief can use brute force in parallel, which will make his work easier rather in case with LUKS-LVM-LUKS.
Questions:

Is this possible? Aren't there any conflicts between LUKS? Will the data be damaged by double encryption?
What are the cons of this method?
Is there the best method solve my task?

p.s. Yes, I know when my LUKS is opened my data is at risk either.

How are julia's and bob's  LUKS volumes going to mounted ? Will julia and bob issue à luksopen and if yes, will they get temporary home dir ? I use a more or less similar setup with a relay user that mount a home_secure dir, then  I could log as main user. home_secure is holding internal web site, database and private stuff.

@Archemar Julia and Bob will mount in current home directory.
